# How to deploy GIT code to EC2 automatically

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have a git repo and local development environment for some Spring Micro-service application. I have a 10 EC2 instance for prod and 5 EC2 instances for test deployment.

For test and prod, we have two different branches of GIT and our plan is that ...

1. First, we will develop code and do unit testing in our local.
2. We will upload the code in git test brunch and deploy the changes in test EC2 instances
3. After the successful test, we will upload the code changes in prod brunch and finally deploy the code prod EC2 instances.

copying the microservice war file in all EC2 instances one by one, for every change, is not a good idea at all I guess. Is there any automated way/service by which I can connect my GIT repo with AWS service, which will compile the code and run build and copy the war file to the specific local in a specific EC2 instance?

That has to be done per project bases, as it is a microservice so,

Procect1 war should go in EC2-1(say one ec2 instance) /home/user/war

Project2 war should go in EC2-2(say another ec2 instance) /home/user/war

something like that.

Comment: This smells like a serverfault.com question. It is also likely to have been asked and answered already, I suspect - this is a very common need. Also, you should look into Kubernetes and Helm.

Comment: can you please provide the link.... that will be great help ...

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/ and https://helm.sh/

Comment: I guess those are not my use .... some understanding mismatch..

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a release [pipeline CI & CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery), now, the how you do it is too broad and depends on many factors.

[image]

You can go very raw using only `git` and implement a workflow using a [post-receive hook](https://nbari.com/post/git-web-deployment-workflow/), up to a "containerized" solution that may or may not apply depending in your case.

If you want to avoid dealing with Jenkins or [buildbot](https://buildbot.net/) you can use services like Travis CI and implement an [AWS CodeDeploy](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/codedeploy/).  In this cases, you relay more on how you use `git`, and the [git-flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) you implement.

[image]

Normally every commit that goes in to `develop` branch is deployed into the test environment and once merged into `master` it goes directly into production, this heavily depends on [webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/) but with some fine tuning works like a charm since at the end the full pipeline can be fully automated

If you are provisioning the instances using something like [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [saltstack](https://saltstack.com/) you could probably take advantage of your setup and just by adding some [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) (like mentioned before) could be the faster rather than dealing with AWS opsworks for example.

Besides these you always have the AWS solutions but like mentioned before this is too broad and very opinionated, what works for someones may not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a build server such as Jenkins to automate this, there are ways that you can have it watch for a commit on a git branch and then trigger a build and deploy job that will compile the code and then deploy it to your instances.